# Representation for the survival function of the multinomial distribution in terms of the Dirichlet density?

Tags: calculus, probability, statistics, multivariable-calculus

Let $K_p\sim \text{Binomial}(n,p)$ where $n\in \mathbb{N}$ and $0 \leq p \leq 1$.

Simple computations show that, for $1 \leq k \leq n-1$ and $p_0\in (0,1)$,

\begin{align}
    \mathbb{P}(K_{p_0} \geq k)
    &= \int_0^{p_0} \frac{d}{d p} \mathbb{P}(K_p \geq k) d p \notag \\[1mm]
    &= \int_0^{p_0} \left[\frac{d}{d p} \sum_{i=k}^n \binom{n}{i} p^i (1 - p)^{n - i}\right] d p \notag \\[1mm]
    &= \int_0^{p_0} \left[\hspace{-1mm}
        \begin{array}{l}
            n \sum_{i=k}^n \binom{n-1}{i-1} \, p^{i-1} (1 - p)^{(n-1) - (i-1)} \\[1mm]
            - n \sum_{i=k}^{n-1} \binom{n-1}{i} \, p^i (1 - p)^{(n-1) - i}
        \end{array}
        \hspace{-1mm}\right] d p \notag \\[1mm]
    &= \int_0^{p_0} \left[\hspace{-1mm}
        \begin{array}{l}
            n \sum_{i=k}^n \binom{n-1}{i-1} \, p^{i-1} (1 - p)^{(n-1) - (i-1)} \\[1mm]
            - n \sum_{j=k+1}^n \binom{n-1}{j-1} \, p^{j-1} (1 - p)^{(n-1) - (j-1)}
        \end{array}
        \hspace{-1mm}\right] d p \quad (\text{with } j = i + 1) \notag \\
    &= \int_0^{p_0} \left[n \binom{n-1}{k-1} \, p^{k-1} (1 - p)^{(n-1) - (k-1)}\right] d p \notag \\
    &= \frac{n!}{(k-1)! (n - k)!} \int_0^{p_0} p^{k-1} (1 - p)^{n-k} d p.
\end{align}

This turns the survival function of the binomial distribution into an integral over the density of the beta distribution.

Is it possible to derive an analogous representation for the survival function of the multinomial distribution in terms of an integral over the density function of the Dirichlet distribution ?

Comment: What do you mean by the survival function of multinomial distribution? I don't know what the CDF of a multinomial distribution supposed to be. Also, a comment, if it helps: It is not surprising that the calculation gave you a beta distribution; you can imagine your Binomial as sum of N Bernoullii(p)s, and you can simulate that by drawing N uniforms and thresholding.  Then, you are just checking where the kth highest uniform lies, which is given by Beta distribution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For any $d\in \mathbb{N}$, the $d$-dimensional simplex and its interior are defined by
\begin{equation}\label{eq:def.simplex}
    \mathcal{S}_d := \big\{\mathbf{s}\in [0,1]^d: \|\mathbf{s}\|_1 \leq 1\big\} \quad \text{and} \quad \mathrm{Int}(\mathcal{S}_d) := \big\{\mathbf{s}\in (0,1)^d: \|\mathbf{s}\|_1 < 1\big\},
\end{equation}
where $\|\mathbf{s}\|_1 := \sum_{i=1}^d |s_i|$ denotes the $\ell_1(\mathbb{R})$ norm.
Given a set of probability weights $\mathbf{p}\in \mathrm{Int}(\mathcal{S}_d)$, the $\mathrm{Multinomial}\hspace{0.2mm}(N,\mathbf{p})$ probability mass function is defined by
\begin{equation}
    p_N(\mathbf{k}) = \frac{N!}{(N - \|\mathbf{k}\|_1)! \prod_{i=1}^d k_i!} \cdot q^{N - \|k\|_1} \prod_{i=1}^d p_i^{k_i}, \quad \mathbf{k}\in \mathbb{N}_0^d \cap N \mathcal{S}_d,
\end{equation}
where $q := 1 - \|\mathbf{p}\|_1 > 0$ and $N\in \mathbb{N}$.

If $U_1,U_2,\dots,U_N$ are i.i.d. $\mathrm{Uniform}(0,1)$'s and $I_k := (p_{j-1}, p_j]$ with the convention $p_0 := 0$, then $\mathbf{K} := (\sum_{i=1}^N 1_{\{U_i\in I_j\}})_{j=1}^d\sim \mathrm{Multinomial}(N,\mathbf{p})$, so that
\begin{align*}
    &\mathbb{P}(K_i\geq k_i, ~\forall i\in [d]) \\
    &\quad= \mathbb{P}(U_{(k_i)} \leq p_1 + p_2 + \dots + p_i, ~\forall i\in [d]) \\
    &\quad= \int_0^{p_1} \int_{u_1}^{p_1+p_2} \dots \int_{u_{d-1}}^{p_1+p_2+\dots+p_d} N! \prod_{i=1}^{d+1} \frac{(u_i - u_{i-1})^{k_i-k_{i-1}-1}}{(k_i - k_{i-1} - 1)!} \mathrm{d} u_1 \mathrm{d} u_2 \dots \mathrm{d} u_d,
\end{align*}
where $u_0 := 0$, $u_{d+1} := 1$, $k_0 := 0$, $k_{d+1} := N+1$.
After the change of variables $v_i = u_i - u_{i-1}, ~i\in [d+1]$ and $j_i = k_i - k_{i-1}, ~i\in [d+1]$, the above is
\begin{align*}
    &\mathbb{P}(K_i\geq k_i, ~\forall i\in [d]) \\
    &\quad= \int_0^{p_1} \int_0^{(p_1 - v_1) + p_2} \dots \int_0^{\sum_{k=1}^{d-1} (p_k - v_k) + p_d} N! \prod_{i=1}^{d+1} \frac{v_i^{j_i-1}}{(j_i - 1)!} \mathrm{d} v_1 \mathrm{d} v_2 \dots \mathrm{d} v_d \notag \\
    &\quad= \int_{\substack{v_1\in p_1\mathcal{S}_1 \\ (v_1,v_2)\in (p_1+p_2)\mathcal{S}_2 \\ \vdots \\ (v_1,v_2,\dots,v_d)\in (\sum_{i=1}^d p_i)\mathcal{S}_d}} \frac{\Gamma(N+1)}{\prod_{i=1}^{d+1} \Gamma(j_i)} \prod_{i=1}^{d+1} v_i^{j_i-1} \mathrm{d} v_1 \mathrm{d} v_2 \dots \mathrm{d} v_d.
\end{align*}